# Why does a drop in gravitational energy result in star contraction

Tags: energy, stars, stellar-evolution, virial-theorem, brown-dwarfs

Consider a gas cloud that is radiating away heat.

From virial theorem we see that if the cloud radiates away heat and loses energy this will cause its gravitational energy to drop. Why does this mean that the star will contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cloud radiates away the heat in its core, then the pressure there which resists further contraction of the cloud will decrease. This then means the cloud's contraction under the influence of gravity will proceed, and the gravitational potential energy of the dispersed cloud gets converted into more compressive heating of the core as it shrinks.

As long as the core can continue to radiate away the heat caused by gravitational contraction, the cloud will just keep on contracting.